# How to build a JavaScript 2D array inside a for

Tags: javascript, arrays

ive searched here and i cant find a solution for this, i think im just missing some syntax.

```
var DataSend = [];
for ( $i=0; $i < $MovimentosLength; $i++) {
    DataSend = [
        $i =[
            'CodProduto', CacheQL.Movimentos.CodProduto[$i],
            'ProdutoDesignacao', CacheQL.Movimentos.ProdutoDesignacao[$i],
            'Valor', CacheQL.Movimentos.Valor[$i],
            'Percentagem', CacheQL.Movimentos.Percentagem[$i]
        ],
    ]

}//#FOR
```

is this possible? I know how to do it in PHP but in js i dont really know the syntax.

Thanks

Comment: You are overwriting that `$i` variable with every loop.

Comment: `DataSend[$i] = ['CodProduto',...]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript

Comment: JavaScript has modernised iteration commands like `for...of` and functional utilities like `Array.prototype.map` and `Array.prototype.reduce` that could probably make this easier to read/write. If you show more code around this problem, we may be able to give you a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there! It's just that with javascript there's no shorthand for pushing to an array. You have to use `push()`.

Also from your example it looks like it's not a 2D array, but an array of objects. Something like this:

```
const DataSend = [];
for (let i=0; i < MovimentosLength; i++)
{
    DataSend.push({
                CodProduto: CacheQL.Movimentos.CodProduto[i],
                ProdutoDesignacao: CacheQL.Movimentos.ProdutoDesignacao[i],
                Valor: CacheQL.Movimentos.Valor[i],
                Percentagem: CacheQL.Movimentos.Percentagem[i]
            });
}
```

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's pretty similar though I don't know what the source CacheQL.Movimentos in your case is. An array too?

Initialize a new array

```
var DataSend=[];
```

loop over the object

```
for(var a=0;a<CacheQL.Movimentos.length;a++)
{
}
```

and inside the for loop push a new array to the existing

```
DataSend.push(['CodProduto', CacheQL.Movimentos.CodProduto[a],
                    'ProdutoDesignacao', CacheQL.Movimentos.ProdutoDesignacao[a],
                    'Valor', CacheQL.Movimentos.Valor[a],
                    'Percentagem', CacheQL.Movimentos.Percentagem[a]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `push` with a valid object literal:

```
for (let i = 0; i < MovimentosLength; i++) {
  DataSend.push({
    CodProduto: CacheQL.Movimentos.CodProduto[i],
    ProdutoDesignaco: CacheQL.Movimentos.ProdutoDesignaco[i],
    Valor: CacheQL.Movimentos.Valor[i],
    Percentagem: CacheQL.Movimentos.Percentagem[i]
  });
}
```

Or if you wanted an array:

```
for (let i = 0; i < MovimentosLength; i++) {
  DataSend.push([
    "CodProduto", CacheQL.Movimentos.CodProduto[i],
    "ProdutoDesignaco", CacheQL.Movimentos.ProdutoDesignaco[i],
    "Valor", CacheQL.Movimentos.Valor[i],
    "Percentagem", CacheQL.Movimentos.Percentagem[i]
  ]);
}
```